# Receiving Email Attachments in App Engine Python errors on Unicode Text File

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, python-2.7, email-attachments

I have some code to parse an email and find the attachments then store them into the Datastore as db.BlobProperties (might change that to Blobstore later).  The problem is that when I send a UTF8 encoded text file it generates an error.

The code basically saves the file and returns a key that is converted to a string then stored in the parent email entity.  As you can see I decode the file then store it as a blob.  I have sent lots of attachments and this code works on everything but Text encoded with Unicode.  Is there a better way to do this?  What can I do to handle Unicode text attachments?

code snipit

```
    my_file = []
    my_list = []
    if hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
        file_name = ""
        file_blob = ""
        for filename, filecontents in mail_message.attachments:
            file_name = filename
            file_blob = filecontents.decode()
            my_file.append(file_name)
            my_list.append(str(store_file(self, file_name, file_blob)))
```

store_file

```
def store_file(self, file_name, file_blob):
    new_file = myblob(file_name = file_name, 
                      file_blob = file_blob)
    return new_file.put()
```

I have tried using `file_blob = str(file_blob)` in the above to no avail.  That just breaks the code and the file never gets stored.

log 1 of Unicode Text File

```
Property file_blob must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/mail_handlers.py", line 65, in post
    self.receive(mail.InboundEmailMessage(self.request.body))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ae-baseapp/1.359073377819595139/controllers/InboundHandler.py", line 51, in receive
    file_list.append(str(store_file(self, file_name, file_blob)))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ae-baseapp/1.359073377819595139/models/MyModel.py", line 63, in store_file
    file_blob = file_blob)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 974, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2780, in validate
    (self.name, self.data_type.__name__, err))
BadValueError: Property file_blob must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument should be str instance, not unicode)
```

Log 2 of removing the filecontents.decode() and replacing it with just filecontents.

```
Property file_blob must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument should be str instance, not EncodedPayload)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1530, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/mail_handlers.py", line 65, in post
    self.receive(mail.InboundEmailMessage(self.request.body))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ae-baseapp/1.359097282640216691/controllers/InboundHandler.py", line 57, in receive
    file_list.append(str(store_file(self, file_name, file_blob)))
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ae-baseapp/1.359097282640216691/models/MyModel.py", line 64, in store_file
    file_blob = file_blob)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 974, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2780, in validate
    (self.name, self.data_type.__name__, err))
BadValueError: Property file_blob must be convertible to a Blob instance (Blob() argument should be str instance, not EncodedPayload)
```

Comment: "It returns an error" is monumentally unhelpful. What error? Post the (complete) stacktrace!

Comment: Added the trace.  I thought it was clear it was returning a Value Error from the post.  Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attachment payloads are instances of the [EncodedPayload](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/mail.py#536) class. Attachments have an encoding and an optional character set. The former refers to transfer encodings such as base64; the latter to character encodings such as UTF-8 (character set's a bit of an outdated and misleading term here). The `EncodedPayload.decode()` method decodes both transfer encoding and text encoding, which as you've noticed is not very helpful if you just want to get the original bytes the user attached to their message.

There's a number of approaches you can take here, but what I'd recommend is duplicating EncodedPayload's logic for decoding transfer encoding, which looks something like this:

```
if filecontents.encoding and filecontents.encoding.lower() != '7bit':
  try:
    payload = filecontents.payload.decode(filecontents.encoding)
  except LookupError:
    raise UnknownEncodingError('Unknown decoding %s.' % filecontents.encoding)
  except (Exception, Error), e:
    raise PayloadEncodingError('Could not decode payload: %s' % e)
else:
  payload = filecontents.payload
```

Note that if the attachment *was* text, you need to include the character encoding when you store it, or there'll be no way to interpret it when you send it back to the user - the original text could have been encoded using any character encoding.

Likewise, you should also save the mimetype of the attachment if you can, but this doesn't appear to be exposed anywhere in the API. You might want to consider avoiding using the IncomingMessage class at all, and instead decoding the body of the POST request using Python's mime message module.

Comment: @MarkFinch If `filecontents` is a string, calling `filecontents.decode()` decodes it into a Unicode string using the system default codec. If your data is base64 encoded, you should be using `base64.b64decode(filecontents)` or `filecontents.decode('base64')`. Mail attachments can be encoded a number of ways, though, and how they're encoded is specified in the attachment's header fields.

Comment: Sorry I was editing the comment when you replied and deleted it as your comment came in because of the 5 min rule.  Correct me if I am wrong, but the file attachments come in as Base64 encoded.  We run decode on them to get them back to their native state. The expected behaviour in my opinion is that if I can store a PDF, DOC, Jpeg, and GIF file using this method then it shouldn't treat a TXT file any different.  Re-encoding it doesn't work in this case as it will generate an error that it expected a str and got x.  I am looking for a work around to deal with this case.

Comment: Filecontents is a text document, that isn't really a string just a different format for a file.  AppEngine treats it as a string anyway. Using a Try Except block gets around the message redelivery problem (thanks again) but the file gets lost since it generates an error about the Unicode.  Someone has had to work around this already.  If storing the files in the blobstore fixes this then I am happy with that answer.  I was going to change it there anyway due to the off chance someone sends an attachment over 1mb.  I would like to find a work around anyway as this might come up in the future.

Comment: As I just said, calling `.decode()` on a string doesn't base64 decode it (by default; there are many codecs available), it decodes it as a unicode string. If what you want is base64 decoding, you're calling the wrong method.

Comment: I decode the file in order to store it in the db.BlobProperty that won't store it unless the .decode is run.  I don't know what encoding is on each mail.  In general it is base64, the point isn't what the original encoding was.  The point is getting the file after it is decoded into the datastore.  Which works on everything but Text files that are not ASCII encoded in this case Unicode.

Comment: Sorry, please ignore my last (now deleted) comment; I see that email attachments are instances of `EncodedPayload` - something we don't apepar to document anywhere.

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstandings. Please see my rewrite of the answer.

Comment: Nick sorry your getting frustrated with me.  In the post I added the log that happens when no .decode() is used.  The Datastore refuses to store it because of it being an EncodedPayload.  There is no way for my application to know what is in the file attachment until it is decoded. Even then there isn't a pythonic way to know. I am dealing with that issue on sending the file to the templates `mimetypes` are only guessing very old formats. Formats such as .ODS/ODT and .docx do not get the proper header. I probably can test for unicode string and then encode it but that would be a hack.

Comment: No problem Nick it's all good.  As I mentioned in the comment I had posted about the time you updated there doesn't seem to be a good way to guess the mimetype I have used Pythons mimetypes module as noted.  I can probably come up with a way to test if the document is unicode before sending it to the datastore, but that cruds up (pun intended) my model or controller with a hack to get around App Engine treating the Text File as a unicode string.  

What is the logic behind the db.BlobProperty requiring a string vs just storing the bytes?  This would be a non issue if it ignored the data.

Comment: @MarkFinch The BlobProperty can't just 'store the bytes', because there's no single canonical encoding for a unicode string. For it to store a unicode string, you first have to pick an encoding and encode it that way yourself. As far as guessing mimetypes of attachments goes, this isn't something you should have to do, if not for the shortcomings of the incoming mail library. I'd suggest using Python's mime message API and decoding the message (sent as the body of the POST request) yourself, which will let you access all the header fields.

Answer (score 2):

Check if this code helps:

===========================

```
   my_file = []
    my_list = []
    if hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
        file_name = ""
        for filename, filecontents in mail_message.attachments:
            file_name = filename
            file_blob = filecontents.payload
            file_blob = file_blob.decode(filecontents.encoding)
            my_file.append(file_name)
            my_list.append(str(store_file(self, file_name, file_blob)))
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did differently than the OP?