# How to store e-mail attachment to GAE Blobstore?

Tags: google-app-engine, email, blobstore, app-engine-ndb

Let's say the app received a message, which [has attachments](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields) (`mail_message.attachments`). Now, I would like to save the message in the datastore. I don't want to store attachment there, so I would like to keep there blobstore keys only. I know that I can [write files to blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). The questions I have:

1. how to extract files from the mail attachment;
2. how to keep original filenames;
3. how to store blob keys in the datastore (taking into account that one mail can contain several attachments looks like `BlobKeyProperty()` doesn't work in this case).

**Upd.** For (1) [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695851/receiving-email-attachments-in-app-engine-python-errors-on-unicode-text-file) can be used:

```
my_file = []
my_list = []
if hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
    file_name = ""
    file_blob = ""
    for filename, filecontents in mail_message.attachments:
        file_name = filename
        file_blob = filecontents.decode()
        my_file.append(file_name)
        my_list.append(str(store_file(self, file_name, file_blob)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I finally do:

```
class EmailHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        '''
        Receive incoming e-mails
        Parse message manually
        '''
        msg = email.message_from_string(self.request.body) # http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html
        for part in msg.walk():
            ctype = part.get_content_type()
            if ctype in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']:
                image_file = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                image_file_name = part.get_filename()
                # save file to blobstore
                bs_file = files.blobstore.create(mime_type=ctype, _blobinfo_uploaded_filename=image_file_name)
                with files.open(bs_file, 'a') as f:
                    f.write(image_file)
                files.finalize(bs_file)
                blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(bs_file)
```

`blob_key`s are stored in the datastore as `ndb.BlobKeyProperty(repeated=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use NDB instead of the (old) datastore. In NDB you can use repeated and structured repeated properties to save a list of BlobProperties and filenames.

See : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties

Comment: Thanks, I use NDB (see the tags).